# How to convert corona game from android to ios

Tags: ios, iphone, coronasdk

I got a Game developed in `Corona` for the android. Now I have to convert this to ios. While compiling the game using the `CoronaSDK` it is working fine on iPhone simulator, only the graphics are a bit off from the position as the game is developed to work on `MDPI` and `HDPI` devices.

My question is, do I just rearrange the graphics according to iPhone screen size or do i have start  with `levelGHelper` and the `spriteHelper`. Please do suggest as I need a starting point to work on this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of game you are making you might want to look into dynamic scaling in your project configuration within Corona.

Since the amount of devices and screen resolutions are so vast I cannot recommend making an application for each resolution/device. Corona already has features that allow you to use a single set of screen coordinates and have those automatically scaled for each device.

Dynamic Scaling handles most of the scaling issues and will automatically scale anything from text to objects and even your images to match the resolution.

You can learn a great deal about dynamic scaling [here.](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/10/modernizing-the-config-lua/) This tutorial takes you through using the modernized "ultimate" config file which I attached below.

```
--calculate the aspect ratio of the device
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth
application = {
   content = {
      width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 800 or math.ceil( 1200 / aspectRatio ),
      height = aspectRatio < 1.5 and 1200 or math.ceil( 800 * aspectRatio ),
      scale = "letterBox",
      fps = 30,

      imageSuffix = {
         ["@2x"] = 1.3,
      },
   },
}
```

I can also suggest you to start reading Coronas own documentation here and pay special attention to the dynamic scaling part: http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html